# Prepared Statement setter in JDBCCursor Item Reader

Tags: java, prepared-statement, spring-batch, setstring

I am setting the value of `String` something like this:

```
ps.setString(1, "'Schema.tablename.Columnname','Schema.tablename.ColumnName'");
```

Then the prepared statement is setting the value as a blank string (`''`).

Do I need escape characters here? I tried escaping the characters, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you need single quote then do it as follows

```
ps.setString(1, "''Schema.tablename.Columnname'',''Schema.tablename.ColumnName''");
```

if don't need single quote then remove them

```
ps.setString(1, "Schema.tablename.Columnname,Schema.tablename.ColumnName");
```

Make sure you remove all single quotes if you dont want them. if want them then make sure for each single quote add extra single quote.